# PHP array_key_exists - loose on some types, strict on another

Tags: php, arrays

Even being relatively well aware of PHP peculiarities, the following [strange behaviour](http://codepad.org/rIm3Ofrm) still got me confused today:

```
// loose
$a = array(true => 'foo');
var_dump(array_key_exists(1, $a));

// strict
$a = array('7.1' => 'foo');
var_dump(array_key_exists('7.10', $a));
```

I wonder what could be the technical reason of this effect, so the question is, what in the process behind this function is causing values of some types to be compared loosely while others are compared strictly? I'm not complaining about the behaviour, but trying to understand that, so there is no point for "PHP sucks" comments.

Comment: Arrays keys are always casted to integers. I thought you'd be confused by `echo '7.1' == '7.10';` ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you think is strange...

Comment: maybe you could add the script output there? First glance though: Boolean as array key? I dont think thats ggonna help in any way! 2nd: 7.10 is not the same at 7.1 - declaring this in '' makes it a string....

Comment: @MikeBrant - meze never stated you couldn't ;) 7.1 or 7.10 however would be floating points, so wouldn't be able to be used as plain integers in array keys, only as strings.

Comment: strings case doesn't concern me, I was confused by true being resolved as 1. but the fact it's cast to integer makes perfect sense, thanks.

Comment: @BenGriffiths nah, that's php. Floats are converted to integers too. '__toString' isn't called on objects, so there's a warning instead...;s

Comment: @BenGriffiths Meze's original comment way that array keys ahd to be strings.  I have now removed my comment since it is no longer applicable after his edit.

Comment: `array_key_exists` does indeed a "loose" comparison, but you notice this only if the keys are of different types. `$a = array('1' => 'foo'); var_dump(array_key_exists(1, $a));` will give you `true`. In the second case, both keys are strings so they are compared as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case, a boolean value is not a valid array key, so it is immediately turned into a 1 when you initialize the array, making your search match.

In your second case, the array key is a string, and '7.1' is not the same string as '7.10'

Comment: Although `true` is not a valid array key, if the key was `'1'`, it would return `true` as well. So type conversion does take place.

Comment: I believe this is because a PHP array, when associative, is dealt with like a hashmap: IE, all strings are converted to integers (the hashes of the string) and then looked up by that.

Comment: @Robert: You are probably right. You cannot have an array with both, `'1'` and `1` as keys, so the internally map to the same value.

Comment: This is all documented at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php.  Specifically, strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, `'7.1'` and `'7.10'` are strings. They are compared as string, so they don't match.

Now why do you have a match in the first example? Array keys can be either strings or integer. So `true` is converted to integer, which evaluates as `1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).  Note that, keys are integers or strings.  Specific key casts are mentioned in the documentation, in particular (for your case) that bools are cast to integers (ie. *true* as 1 and *false* as 0).  As noted elsewhere, your other examples are strings (remove the quotes to make them floats, which would then be truncated to integers as per the docs).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could add the script output there? First glance though: Boolean as array key? I dont think thats gonna help in any way! 2nd: 7.10 is not the same at 7.1 - declaring this in '' makes it a string....

if you want true as a keyname, then you need to encapsulate it in either single or double quotes. IF you dont know about PHP and single/double quotes, it will cause the contents to be treated as a string value rather than Integer of Boolean (True/False)